Gatsby markdown pages without gatsby-node.js
The gatsby documentation is a little confusing on when to use pages using the file system route API and when to use a gatsby-node file with a createPages function.
I am trying to go the route of just using the file system route. Which, if I understand the documentation correctly, you do NOT create a file in the templates folder. Rather, you create a file in the pages folder that is named according to some variables.
I have some markdown files in /src/content/interviews. The markdown files contain frontmatter that has a slug field.
In gatsby-config, I have the interviews folder set up like this:
        {
            resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
            options: {
                "name": "interviews",
                "path": "./src/content/interviews/"
            },
            __key: "interviews"
        },
        'gatsby-transformer-remark',

and then I created a page called /src/pages/interviews/{markdownRemark.frontmatter__slug}.tsx
That page has this code:
import React, {FC} from "react";
import {graphql} from "gatsby";

export const InterviewPage: FC<any> = ({data})=>{
    return <div>
        <h1>{data.frontmatter.title}</h1>
    </div>
}

const pageQuery = graphql`
  query($id: String!) {
    markdownRemark(id: { eq: $id }) {
      html
      frontmatter {
        date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
        slug
        title
      }
    }
  }
`

If I run this query in the GraphQL tester, I see my files:
query MyQuery {
  markdownRemark {
    wordCount {
      paragraphs
      sentences
      words
    }
    html
  }
}

However, I see no pages are being created in sitePage collection. For some reason they are not being picked up.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. From what I can see in the docs I should have everything correct without trying to go down the gatsby-node path. Anything obvious that I'm missing?

I was able to solve this by switching to the MDX plugin instead of using gatsby-transformer-remark. Here is the relevant part of my config now:
        {
            resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
            options: {
                extensions: [`.mdx`, `.md`],
                gatsbyRemarkPlugins: [
                    {
                        resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
                        options: {
                            maxWidth: 1000,
                            quality: 80,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        },
        "gatsby-plugin-sharp",
        "gatsby-transformer-sharp",
        {
            resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
            options: {
                "name": "content",
                "path": "./content"
            },
            __key: "interviews"
        },
        {
            resolve: `gatsby-plugin-page-creator`,
            options: {
                path: `./content`,
            },
        },

and then my page file (/src/pages/interviews/page.tsx) looks like this:
const InterviewPage: FC<any> = (props, context) => {
    console.log(props)
    console.log(context)
    const data = props.data
    const first = data.allMdx.edges[1].node
    return <div>
        <h1>{first.frontmatter.title}</h1>
        <MDXProvider>{first.body}</MDXProvider>
    </div>
}

export default InterviewPage

export const pageQuery = graphql`
 query InterviewPageQuery {
  allMdx(filter: {frontmatter: {type: {eq: "interview"}}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        frontmatter {
          date
          slug
          title
          type
        }
        tableOfContents
        body
      }
    }
  }
}
`

`


I haven't figured out path parameters yet. But so far this is working! No gastby-node.js file needed.

The DSL in file-system routing is using {type_name}.{path_to_field}.
It should be /src/pages/interviews/{MarkdownRemark.frontmatter__slug}.tsx instead of /src/pages/interviews/{markdownRemark.frontmatter__slug}.tsx.
